# Black screen on the simulator when do back in navigation bar after using search Bar

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

Let's say I have two UIViewControllers: Home and Detail. 
Home is tableViewController with searchBar at its top. 
When i do the search, and accede to the Detail  viewController, all works fine.

But, when i do Back in the navigation Bar to return to the Home viewController, black screen is showed. (neither my initial table nor the table resulted from the search !).

Any adea how to resolve this ? 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you wrote any code in the view will appear of home screen

Comment: Sorry, no ! i didn't write any thing there ...

Comment: I found out the mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found !

To get to the detail view, i asked my segue twice ! 
I  removed the wrong one and it works !